# Multiple dropdown selection from javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal that contains a dropdown list that can select multiple options, i've tried many methods but my javascript wont execute do what i need. When the button is clicked, i need the javascript to select a value from the options under the said dropdown list. It does not select anything.

```js
//alert(response[i].daytype);
              var daywhen = response[i].daytype.toString();
              var trimmed = daywhen.split(',');
              var length = trimmed.length;
              //alert(trimmed[0]+trimmed.length);
              document.getElementById(2).selected = "true";
              document.getElementById(1).selected = "true";
              for(x = 0;x<length;x++){
               alert(trimmed[x]);
               document.getElementById("1").selected = "true";
               document.getElementById("esched").selectedIndex = 2;
```

```html
<div class="col" id="escheduledropdown" style="display:none;"><label id="etypeofsched"></label><!-- list of week or months if not daily -->
     <select id="esched" name="esched" class="form-control col selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" multiple="multiple">
      <!-- fill data using javascript -->
      <option value="1" id="1">Monday</option>
      <option value="2" id="2">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="3" id="3">Wednesday</option>
      <option value="4" id="4">Thursday</option>
      <option value="5" id="5">Friday</option>
      <option value="6" id="6">Saturday</option>
      <option value="0" id="0">Sunday</option>
     </select> 
     <input type="hidden" name="hiddenschedule2" id="hiddenschedule2" value="">
    </div>
```

Note: The commented alerts are executed so i know the javascript is executed. it just wont read the elementbyid.

Comment: What is response?  You are also missing an end } in javascript snippet

Comment: set `.selected = true` instead of `.selected = "true"`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @karen , response was from the ajax, it prints the ID that i need.

Comment: @gvk thanks dude it worked!